# Как получить полную ссылку запроса в Play framework scala

Tags: oauth, scala, playframework

Мне необходима очень простая вещь. Мне нужно получить ссылку вида

> /oauth#access_token=bkakak&tralala=trululi

Очевидно, для oauth регистрации и авторизации. Итак, вопрос : как получить полную строку запроса? В контроллере или routes, не имеет значения.

```
request.path request.url request.rawQueryString request.queryString
```

уже пробовал. Спасибо!

Comment: Привет, я не внимательно прочитал url. По этому не верно ответил. Символ - # который используется называется "Fragment identifier". Он не отправляется браузером на сервер. Можете проверить перехватив запрос скажем в консоли браузера. Передавайте параметры в теле url(GET запрос) или в теле запроса(POST запрос). "Fragment identifier" нужен для навигации по документу а не не для обмена сообщениями между клиентом и сервером.

Comment: Короче, все передал через javascript и не парился в итоге.

Comment: @AlexanderduSautoy, твой комментарий и должен быть ответом :)

Answer (score 0):

Получить play.api.mvc.Request, у него вызвать соответсвующие метод: uri().
Пример:

```
def echo = Action { request =>
  Ok("Request url: [" + request.url() + "]")
}
```

О play.api.mvc.Request читайте: https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Request

Пример взять из: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaActions#What-is-an-Action?

Comment: You are wrong: I have tried it, it only gives /oauth, so it isn 't a solution